# TYPO3 v10 - Custom text "Forgot your password?" Backend Login

Tags: authentication, label, typo3, translate, typo3-10.x

TYPO3 v10.4.15

I have a custom file translate (xlf), and I'm trying to translate the BE login, a example is the next:

```
<trans-unit id="login.submit" resname="login.submit" approved="yes">
 <source>Login</source>
 <target state="final">Iniciar sesión</target>
</trans-unit>
    
<trans-unit id="forgot_password" resname="forgot_password" approved="yes">
 <source>Forgot your password?</source>
 <target>¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</target>
</trans-unit>
```

The first is correct, but the second not work, someone know the id for label "Forgot your password?" or if is another cause.

Answer (score 0):

The id for the label you're looking for is `login.password_forget`.

All labels for backend localization are located in `typo3/sysext/backend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf`.

Apparently you're trying to translate the TYPO3 backend to Spanish. It would be wonderful if you could contribute your translation to the official TYPO3 translation project. We're using Crowdin to manage all translations.

In the official [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/Internationalization/TranslationServer/Crowdin.html) you can read more how translation works. If you need support to get started, please join the [TYPO3 Slack channel #typo3-translations](https://typo3.slack.com/archives/C032FRT0W). If you don't have a Slack account yet, you can get one via [my.typo3.org](https://my.typo3.org/).